# Installing PHP PECL memcached extension on CentOS 5.6

Tags: php, centos, memcached

I would like to setup memcached on my server so that I can learn how to use it. It is my understanding that the basic requirements to use it with PHP are:

- PHP
- memcached
- PHP PECL memcached library

After successfully installing and running `php53` via `yum`, I have tried running

```
yum install php-pecl-memcached
```

The following is a portion of the output from `yum` when trying to install `php-pecl-memcached`:

```
--> Processing Conflict: php53-common conflicts php-common
```

I need to stick with `php 5.3` so I cannot fall back to the `yum php` package (php 5.1).

It seems that there was a IUS repo with a package named `php53u`, according to [this site](http://www.ninjanerd.com/installing-php-53-pecl-and-memcache-centos-ius-yum-repository), but I can't use that repo.

I would also like to avoid installing from source.

Is there a solution out there for installing the PECL memcached extension on CentOS 5.6, with PHP 5.3?

**Output of `yum repolist`:**

```
    [~]$ yum repolist
    Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
    Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
     * base: mirror.wiredtree.com
     * epel: mirror.steadfast.net
     * extras: mirror.wiredtree.com
     * updates: mirrors.serveraxis.net
    repo id                                                                        repo name                                                                                                                 status
    base                                                                           CentOS-5 - Base                                                                                                           3,566
    chl                                                                            CHL Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - x86_64                                                                                  8
    chl-source                                                                     CHL Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - x86_64 - Source                                                                         0
    epel                                                                           Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - x86_64                                                                            6,720
    extras                                                                         CentOS-5 - Extras                                                                                                           235
    updates                                                                        CentOS-5 - Updates                                                                                                          225
    repolist: 10,754
```

**Output of `rpm -qa | grep php`**

```
    [~]$ rpm -qa | grep php
    php53-cli-5.3.3-1.el5_6.1
    php53-common-5.3.3-1.el5_6.1
    php53-5.3.3-1.el5_6.1
```

Comment: Looks like you are mixing up `php-*` with `php53-*`. Please show us the output of `yum repolist` and `rpm -qa | grep php`?

Comment: @quanta - I just posted the output that you requested.

Comment: Why you would like to avoid installing from source? Also check out the @SparX's answer.

Comment: @quanta - I don't think I'm mixing up `php-*` with `php53-*`. I have tried setup #1: installing `php53-*` with `php-pecl-memcached`, and setup #2: installing `php-*` with `php-pecl-memcached`. I am certain that setup #1 is not even supposed to work since `php-pecl-memcached` seems not to work with `php53`. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @quanta - I am still very new to package management and linux server admin. I am trying to stick to pre-compiled packages for now. If installing the PECL Memcached extension on CentOS 5 must be done from source, then I don't have a choice. But that is part of my question - is there a solution aside from installing from source. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I was able to do it this way:

```
# Install IUS repo
[~] wget http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/Redhat/5/x86_64/ius-release-1.0-8.ius.el5.noarch.rpm
[~] rpm -Uvh  ius-release-1.0-8.ius.el5.noarch.rpm

# Install PHP 5.3
# This installs php53u-cli and php53u-common as well
[~] yum install php53u

# Install the PHP PECL Memcache extension!
[~] yum install php53u-pecl-memcache

# Restart spawn-fcgi (refreshes PHP instance)
[~] /etc/init.d/php_cgi restart
```

Comment: Well, in your question you said you can't use that repo and at last you  had to depend on tat :) Also be aware that memcache & memcached are two different pecl extensions. So the functions may differ depending on the extension you are using.

Comment: @SparX - Thanks! I did not catch that the two extensions are different. I think initially I was unable to use the IUS repo because I had a dead URL. I just needed to find an up-to-date one.

Answer (score 2):

Install php53u and then install php53u-pecl-memcache. That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try

```
pecl install memcached
```

instead? Assuming you already have **php-pear** installed.

Comment: yum reports a conflict between php53-common (installed) and php-common (php-pear dependency?)